# cdkDropListGroup - error Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node

Tags: angular, angular-material

Im using Drag and Drop from angular material @angular/cdk/drag-drop

````
       <div *ngFor="let sectionData of tableSectionsData"
            cdkDropList
            [cdkDropListData]=sectionData.list
            (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
            da-table-section
            [id]=sectionData.id
            [sectionData]="sectionData"
            (removeField)="removeField($event, sectionData.sectionType)"
            (closeFieldsSelectionPanel)="closePanel()"
       >
       </div>
       <ng-template #fieldsSelectionPanel>
           <da-visual-pivot-field-selection-panel (addField)="addFieldToTableSectionAccordingToType($event)"
                                                  (closePanel)="closePanel()"></da-visual-pivot-field-selection-panel>
       </ng-template>

   </div>```

I can drag perfectly items from down to upper list but from up to down list I get the following error:
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
````

Comment: you need a cdkDrag (or div or span or something) inside your cdkDropLists.

Comment: I already have it